# Prove the Funk-Necke formula

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> $$\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{|\xi|=1}e^{i \xi\cdot y} \, \mathrm dS = \frac{\sin|y|}{|y|}; \qquad y \in \mathbb{R}^3.$$

**Hint:** W.L.O.G, you can assume $y=|y| \widehat{y}$ where $\widehat{y}=(0,0,1).$
Could any one help me with that ,thank you.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: I've tried, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you understand what a dot product is, and what $dS$ is? Because that's all you need to use the given hint, and the hint makes it quite easy once you use it.

Comment: Using surface integral and Multiple integral you mean?

Comment: Yeah, try that?

Comment: I've tried actually and didn't see where I can get the RHS sine function. Maybe I massed up my calculation. Could you be so kind to  show me how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: show your computation?

Comment: For starters, do you know why no generality is lost if you make that assumption about $y\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Not really, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $\ell=|y|$, then the third component $\xi_3 = \cos\phi$, so
$$ \text{LHS} = \frac{1}{4π} \int_{θ = 0}^{2π} \int_{\phi = 0}^π e^{i\ell\cos\phi} \sin \phi\, d\phi \,dθ=\frac{-1}{2l}e^{i\ell\cos\phi}\Bigg|_{\phi=0}^π = \frac{\sin \ell}{\ell} $$

Ill leave it to you to explain why the hint works(symmetry).

Comment: Why you let $\xi_3=cos \phi$,  I let   $\xi_3=\sqrt{1-\xi_1^2-\xi_2^2}$, is it the same?

Comment: @steve do you know how to compute surface integrals?